# How to mount a NTFS partition in /etc/fstab?

Tags: fstab, automount

I have two partitions that I want to mount on startup:

```
/dev/sda3   /mnt/devel  ext4    defaults    0   2
/dev/sda2   /mnt/excess ntfs    defaults    0   2
```

The `ext4` partition mounts fine (owned by me, writable only by me), but the `NTFS` mounts owned by `root` with R\W permission for all.

How to fix this?

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 amanda amanda 4096 2012-03-14 19:07 devel
drwxrwxrwx  1 root   root   4096 2012-03-14 22:38 excess
```

Comment: The options "noatime" or "relatime" is available and recommended for permanent ntfs mounting (see man mount.ntfs). I had some hdd busy-ness problems with ext3/4 and ntfs too!

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Permissions for ntfs and vfat file systems must be set with the `dmask`, `fmask` and `umask` options. `dmask` controls permissions for directories, `fmask` controls permissions for files, and `umask` controls both. Since these options set *masks*, they should be the complement of the permissions you want. For example, rwx for the owner and rx for others is 022 rather than 755.

To set the owner, use the `uid` and `gid` options for user and group, respectively. You can find your UID with the command `id -u`. To find your GID, use `id -g`. These values are both usually 1000.

A common set of mount options for ntfs is `uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137`. This sets you as the owner of the drive, and sets the permissions to `drwxr-x---`.

Here are examples of a working /etc/fstab

```
UUID=EEA2B69CA2B668AB        /WIN_C     ntfs-3g   defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,dmask=027,fmask=137,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0 
UUID=65AEC0E830EA0497        /WIN_D     ntfs-3g   rw 0 0
```

- To get the **UUID** for your partition, you can use `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/` or `lsblk -f | grep -v loop` or **gnome-disks**
- **If you get no visible error after rebooting and partitions stay readonly or you get an error similar to:**

```
    Error mounting /dev/sda6 at /media/WindowsDrive: 
    Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda6" "/media/rolindroy/Media Center"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0). 
    Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount. 
    Failed to mount '/dev/sda6': Operation not permitted The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. 
    Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option
```

This is because Windows 8 and 10 offer a "Fast Startup" option that depends on a "non-complete" shutdown.  You can disable fast startup by following these [steps](https://itsfoss.com/solve-ntfs-mount-problem-ubuntu-windows-8-dual-boot/) under "Power Options".

```
UUID=01D9318DD8A39810  /run/media/$user/Win11   ntfs-3g uid=$user,gid=$user,umask=0022 0 0
UUID=01D9317B8D647610  /run/media/$user/Storage ntfs-3g uid=$user,gid=$user,umask=0022 0 2
```

In the above example win11 will be mounted read-only, while Storage as read-write.

& they will be visible in file manager as drives Since they are mounted in folder /run/media/$user
Also don't forget to replace $user with your username.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#ntfs

Comment: Thanks. The "mask" part of masking threw me for a loop. `111` gets you `-rw-rw-rw-` not `---x--x--x`

Comment: Could you possibly provide a more complete example showing those options used in a line from `/etc/fstab`

Comment: @puk, I have `UUID=3030BD846F74E514     /media/iam/ntfspartition  ntfs-3g    uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=022,fmask=133    0       0`, as I've included at http://askubuntu.com/a/507326/221448 (where I also mention `bind`).

Comment: how do I set the drive owner to root in the fstab?

Comment: @ScottF `uid=0,gid=0`

Comment: This params worked for me: "defaults,rw,nls=utf8,umask=000,dmask=027,fmask=137,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names". After this, also run "sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXX" to fix the partition.

Comment: Is it better to set the file system type to `ntfs` or `ntfs-3g`?

Comment: @AaronFranke https://serverfault.com/q/304354/333603

Comment: what is the difference between the two example lines you have shown? If they are functionally similar, the second one looks much simpler

Comment: What does `mount` show as type for such a mount point? fuseblk?

Answer (score 44):

If you mount the ntfs partition with the permissions option, then chmod / chown will work

```
/dev/sda2   /mnt/excess ntfs-3g    permissions,locale=en_US.utf8    0   2
```

You can then

```
sudo chown your_user:your_user /mnt/excess
```

Easier then uid,dmask,fmask.

Comment: Any downside/side-effect to that `sudo chown` command? What exactly it does?

Comment: The chown command changes the owner of the mount point (/mnt/excess) to the desired user. This step will have to be repeated each time the partition is mounted, in my experience (at least after every reboot) ... so, do the proper thing, set uid/gid/umask ... I always thought fmask and dmask were optional - like when you wanted different permissions for files and dirs.

Answer (score 13):

I had some trouble with this because when I reboot the disk name changes... (*sda0 to sdb2*)

I fixed the problem by mounting them by UUID in the fstab, you can view the UUID for your harddrives by entering: `sudo blkid`

Make a back-up of your fstab file:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.orig
```

**Make sure you tripple check the >>, if you place one > you overwrite your fstab!**

```
sudo blkid >> /etc/fstab
```

If you still screwed up you can replace your fstab with the original:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab.orig /etc/fstab
```

Next make a folder:

```
sudo mkdir /media/mydrivename
```

Configure the fstab:

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
```

Don't forget to comment the output from the blkid with a '#' on the beginning of the lines!

Add this to the fstab file, you can find the UUID in the block on the bottom you inserted with the command above. *media/mydrivename* is where the partition should be mounted.

```
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   /media/mydrivename ntfs    permissions,locale=en_US.utf8    0   2
```

This is my fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=5d4940cf-5cf5-443a-be11-1f7e551962d1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=84b7e5e9-08c3-4641-b28b-99e0255e604d none            swap    sw              0       0

# 500 GB Webserver harddisk from lr-serv-01
UUID=BA9A48D39A488E37 /media/hdd1 ntfs permissions,locale=en_US.utf8 0 2

# 2 TB Movie share harddisk from lr-serv-01
UUID=7EB09666B09624A5 /media/hdd2 ntfs permissions,locale-en_US.utf8 0 2

#/dev/sda1: UUID="10EC004DEC003010" TYPE="ntfs" 
#/dev/sda2: LABEL="system" UUID="88A4FE47A4FE3772" TYPE="ntfs" 
#/dev/sda3: LABEL="storage_01" UUID="BA9A48D39A488E37" TYPE="ntfs" 
#/dev/sdb1: LABEL="storage_02" UUID="7EB09666B09624A5" TYPE="ntfs" 
#/dev/sdc1: UUID="84b7e5e9-08c3-4641-b28b-99e0255e604d" TYPE="swap" 
#/dev/sdc2: UUID="5d4940cf-5cf5-443a-be11-1f7e551962d1" TYPE="ext4" 
#/dev/sdd1: LABEL="storage_spotnet" UUID="EC6E8F416E8F0394" TYPE="ntfs" 
#/dev/sdd2: LABEL="storage_backup_pcs" UUID="6C2699D026999BA0" TYPE="ntfs" 
#/dev/sdd5: LABEL="storage_series" UUID="7670ABF770ABBC6D" TYPE="ntfs" 
#/dev/sdd6: LABEL="storage_winmx" UUID="564AB81B4AB7F5B9" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Reboot the system by typing:

```
sudo reboot
```

To check if the partition is mounted you can type `df -k`.

Give ownership to yourself:

```
sudo chown -R USERNAME:USERNAME /media/mydrivename
```

**Did this on Ubuntu Server 14.04.01**!

Hope this answer helps someone ;-)

Comment: While this sounds like generally solid advice, I would find it more elegant to simply copy the UUID from the output of `sudo blkid` instead of dumping the whole thing to `/etc/fstab` and transiently corrupt it. Another way would be to get the UUID from the properties dialogue of the partition in GParted.

Comment: Well as I am doing this on my server I don't really see a way to copy it... All I have is a keyboard and bash.

Comment: Most terminal emulators allow you to copy things (assuming you're using remote access or a terminal emulator like `screen` or `tmux` instead of a raw virtual terminal).

Comment: Bad assumption haha, I was not using a terminal emulator. However, I added some stuff to my answer for making a copy of the fstab file in case someone screws up. :)

Comment: I switched from using UUID to LABEL because for some reason the UUID's changed when I adjusted a partition but the label names didn't.  Also I find it easier to see what's going on in fstab with a LABEL="some-name" than a UUID="long random string".

Answer (score 9):

You can use **ntfs-config** GUI utility to mount NTFS partitions in fstab.

[image: Mount NTFS Windows Partition FSTAB]

`ntfs-3g` driver is required to provide full read-write support for the NTFS partition and gksu to run NTFS Configuration GUI with root privileges.

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g ntfs-config
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Search for and open ‘NTFS Configuration Tool’ from the Unity Dash.
In the window that appears select the partitions you want to configure. Here, I would prefer to have only my storage partition mounted. Just tick ‘Enable write support for internal device’.

NTFS-Config Utility will backup the original fstab file, so we can easily review the changes that were made by the application. To review the changes,

```
cat /etc/fstab-ntfs-config-save
cat /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 7):

I use the following that I find correctly gives me permissions upon mount (NTFS drive from a dual-boot system setup):

Edit `/etc/fstab`:

UUIDs can be found in `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` (usually map to `/dev/sd*`)

*Replace `<your uuid>` with your UUID*

`UUID=<your uuid> /mnt/e ntfs auto,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137 0 0`

Answer (score 6):

Might not be a good solution , but you can always map user id to your own one , or the group id:

Just an example here , my user id was 1000

`/dev/sda5 /mnt/excess  ntfs defaults,uid=1000,rw  0  0`

In that case , all files mounted owned by user ided 1000

Comment: That works, but with or with out the "rw" option, it still mounts with permissions `drwxrwxrwx`

Comment: This works for me. For the permissions, I added to fstab file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770

Answer (score 5):

Note that if you mount your ntfs drive ***using a label*** and wish to be able to change the permissions of directories or files on this drive then the following works well (edit the /etc/fstab e.g. sudo nano /etc/fstab and then add):

```
LABEL=Portable_HD_2TB      /media/mintbox2/Portable_HD_2TB ntfs    permissions,defaults        0       2
```

Whereas the below would **NOT** allow you to change permissions of directories or 
files:

```
LABEL=Portable_HD_2TB      /media/mintbox2/Portable_HD_2TB ntfs    defaults        0       2
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Linux kernel version 5.15 (so Ubuntu 22.04 and newer, plus older LTS releases by way of HWE), [a new NTFS implementation](https://lwn.net/Articles/847791/) is available, called `ntfs3`. For the most part, just changing `ntfs-3g` to `ntfs3` in `fstab` entries or `mount` commands seems to work fine. This one natively supports POSIX permissions without needing additional mount options, so the behaviour there is a bit different, even if the options work.

Setting up a test filesystem:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/foo bs=1M count=100
sudo losetup -f /tmp/foo
sudo mkntfs /dev/loop0
```

Then:

```
% mkdir ntfs-test
% sudo mount /dev/loop0 -t ntfs3 ntfs-test
% df -hT ntfs-test                   
Filesystem     Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0     ntfs3  100M  2.5M   98M   3% /home/muru/ntfs-test
```

Permissions in action:

```
% touch ntfs-test/{executable,not-executable}
% chmod uo+x ntfs-test/executable 
% ls -l ntfs-test 
total 0
-rwxr--r-x 1 muru muru 0 Jan 30 21:09 executable
-rw-r--r-- 1 muru muru 0 Jan 30 21:09 not-executable
% sudo chown nobody:gdm ntfs-test/not-executable
% ls -l ntfs-test 
total 0
-rwxr--r-x 1 muru   muru 0 Jan 30 21:09 executable
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody gdm  0 Jan 30 21:09 not-executable
```

The [`fmask`, `dmask` and `umask` options](https://static.lwn.net/kerneldoc/filesystems/ntfs3.html) are still supported, but only affect *newly* created files. Existing files and directories from Windows seem to get a mode of `r-x` (no write) for everybody.