# Lock icon in external drive's folders

Tags: directory, external-hdd, lock

When I attach the external hard drive, the folders have a lock icon on them and i am unable to delete them.

I tried to use `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME` but to no avail, this did not work.
Please tell how to remove that icon and edit the read-only permission.

Comment: Were those files created in Windows environment?

Comment: No, but they were transferred to hard drive in windows platform.

Comment: Are you able to open those files?

Comment: yes,able to copy and paste new files but unable to delete files

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when using an NTFS-formatted drive and is due to how NTFS/Windows handles file permissions (in short, not how the *nix world does it).

You have to adjust your fstab settings to mount the drive with appropriate permissions. [This related question has more details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-do-i-correctly-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab), but the basics of it are that you want to set the `uid` and `gid` values to your user and group. This mounts it as your user, instead of as root.

Comment: Hi, my system was like this, the icons were with a lock on it. then I saw in a forum that the partition should be in trouble, and because it is an external drive, with Windows partition (NTFS) I preferred to open the drive in Windows and have it scan, Windows has encountered errors and corrected them. After that, Linux no longer showed the padlock on the icon. (P.S.: This probably happened because I removed the device without first ejecting it) Picture of padlock: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK5mB.png

Comment: (Tags that I used until I found an answer: e-sata error, external usb hdd, read only, fuseblk, ro, mount, fstab, files locked, can not eject)