# Permission denied when writing a file to new filesystem

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, fstab

Upon installation, I have created an extra partition and mounted it as `/data`. The partition is visible, but I get a `Permission denied` error when trying to create a file or directory in it. Doing it with `sudo` does work.

I am using ext4 filesystem. Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64.

I have tried deleting the partition, then creating it again and setting up `fstab` to use a new partition. That changed nothing.

How do I make the extra partition behave normally, e.g. be writable by users?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For new `ext4` etc filesystem, you need to change the permissions so your user can access it and read/write to it - using for example:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /data
```

<sup>Where `/data` is the path to where the drive is mounted - if you do this in the wrong place it will likely break things.

`$USER` is replaced with the user's username by the shell.</sup>

For more info read the `chown` manual page [[ 1]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/chown.1.html) [[2]](http://ss64.com/bash/chown.html):

```
man chown
```

And to view permissions on stuff you can use `ls -ld /data` for a directory, and `ls -l /data` for the files in it.

For some other filesystems - e.g. NTFS, you can specify the permissions via the mount options - see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/113746/178596).

Comment: Does that mean that only one user (the owner) will be able to write to it?

Comment: Yes, depending on the read/write permissions for 'other' users (see [chmod](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) as well). You can make a group of users if you want more than one user to access the partition, and then replace the second `$USER` with that group name.

Comment: Exactly what should I enter instead of `$USER:$USER`?

Comment: The shell should replace `$USER` - e.g. with mine it will do `wilf`. The first one specifies the user that will be owner, and the second the group. If not sure read the manual :)