# Windows partition not mounting

Tags: 14.04, windows, shutdown, windows-10

hello guys I am facing a problem that my Windows partition is not mounting in Ubuntu I kind of get the error that Windows maybe hibernated or has not been properly shutdown. But the thing is I have completely shutdown Windows but I'm still facing this error. Can somebody tell me why am I facing this error. I am using Windows 10

Comment: Citing from the potential duplicate: "Windows 8 does not actually completely shutdown when you choose shutdown", same counts for Windows 10 if *Fast startup* is activated. Do the advices of the other question help?

Comment: @Marcus I have turned off the Fast Startup option but that doesn't helps

Comment: Did you were managed to mount the partition at all? You may want to mention in your question which steps you already commenced.

Comment: @Marcus it was working all right. I have windows and ubuntu for  a long time. I just upgraded Windows from 8.1 to  10. I was able to mount all of the partitions but yestarday I started to face this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know why I was facing this error but I turned off the hibernation mode and the windows partition is now mounting

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Windows 8 does not really shutdown, but uses some kind of hibernation (fastboot) by default (even if you think you have shut down windows properly).

Ubuntu is detecting this hibernation file created by fastboot and therefore refuses to mount the windows partition writeable - with good reason. Otherwise you could do changes on this partition which Windows would not detect.

From my point of view there are two solutions:

- Disable fastboot in windows: [How to enable / disable fast startup in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/957081/how-to-enable-disable-fast-startup-in-windows-10) or [How to disable or enable Fast Startup in Windows 10](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-or-enable-fast-startup-in-windows-10/)
- use the windows partition readonly (that is not writable) in Ubuntu: there you need to adjust the config file `/etc/fstab` and add the parameter `ro` for this partition. Further reading: [How do I correctly mount a NTFS partition in /etc/fstab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-do-i-correctly-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab)

I clearly recommend to disable fastboot, especially if you have not modified `/etc/fstab` before.

Comment: I know about the fast boot and that option is disabled. I have been using windows and ubuntu for a long time and yesterday i started to get this error

Comment: I had the same problem, got it fixed after an update.
Sorry that I don't remember the update correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has 3 Solution:

1.Login to your Windows 10 and Restart it (Don't Shutdown).Now, login to Ubuntu.Your partition will be mounted

2.Disable Fastboot form Windows 10

3.Remove Windows and use Ubuntu as a single operating system

Comment: the first two didn't work out for me so I just disabled the hibernation mode