# Dual boot write permission problem "destination is read only"

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, ntfs, read-only

I am having a dual boot system. I can read files from the Windows partition in Linux but can't write to it. It's showing

> destination is read only

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

In Windows 10 if fast boot is activated this the problem could arise

**Solution 1:**
You can fully shutdown your Windows 10 operating system then boot to Ubuntu.

To fully shutdown your Windows 10 Press and Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> Key and Click on Shutdown menu

**Solution 2:**
Your can turn off Windows 10's fast boot or Hibernation by following below steps

1. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> button on the keyboard to open Start menu
2. Now write `cmd` in search box
3. In search result list, right click on Command Prompt and Click on Run As Administrator
4. Now type `powercfg.exe /hibernate off` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Shutdown Windows 10 Operating System
6. Boot to Ubuntu (Hope your problem will be fixed).

Comment: disabling fast boot worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can find your answer here.

[Ubuntu mounts external ntfs drive as read-only?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958556/ubuntu-mounts-external-ntfs-drive-as-read-only/958611)

1. Ensure you have fastboot disabled
2. Ensure you have ntfs-3g installed

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
   ```
3. Remount the windows partition

   **Find Windows partition**

   ```
   lsblk -f
   ```

   **Mount Windows partition**

   ```
   sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda# /mnt/windows
   ```