# I cant write/delete anything on my Laptop disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, ntfs, disk

I'm very desesperated, i found today when i started the pc that i cant write in my disk partition containing windows(i have a dual boot, one partition with window sand another with Lubuntu 18.04). The problem is also present in Windows, so i cant create files on mi own disk on windows too. I found on internet that the problem could be causated by an error on shut down the PC. 2 days aog, Freecol(a game) freezes on my linux 2 times and i had to shut down manually the pc(i cant even move my mouse in these moments, idk what happened).
When i started the pc it had worked normally, but yesterday i enteres windows and do some things(installed a apllication truested, bigfishgames) and today i found this.
Idk what to do, i dont have another disk to replace this, and we are on lockdown here.
Someone have a clue of how solve this? I have a USB stick with lubuntu bootable for emergencies, but i dont wanna lost all my data(some are important) and had to reinstall all again(windows and lubuntu).

Thanks for reading all this.

Comment: You didn't say how you forced shutdown; if it was a clean shutdown (eg. system SysRq keys to tell kernel to shutdown/reboot) it won't impact your system, however if you achieved shutdown via unclean methods (eg. cutting power or holding power button..) I would boot your 'live' media (Lubuntu install media using 'try') and check your drive health (mostly just my habit) then `fsck` or file-system check your disk. If that didn't resolve it, I'd read messages and look for your file system being mounted RO or read-only (or flipping to RO due to errors (hardware/logical errors))

Comment: The forced shutdown was holding power button, it was impossible to use mouse and keyboard, i dont know why. I searched a bit on google and i find a way to get rights in the windows system to dele/use files(i think that they will be some only, because the process freezes to and i have to shut down the pc(using the shut down option in the menu this time), so im using a command called chkdsk for checking the healt of the disk,and it is checking as invalid .html files that i created in linux(i dont know why), plus that i found in the W10 notification bar that the unit would have some errors

Comment: So i will try to "fix" these errors on windows and go to linux to check what have changed.

Comment: Edit: I was using this guide: https://askubuntu.com/questions/834269/unable-to-mount-a-windows-partition-in-write-mode?noredirect=1&lq=1 but chkdisk trows me an error: chkdsk cannot continue in read-only mode so i dont know how continue @guiverc

Comment: Look up how to run a SMART test on your disk.

Comment: I have runned the SMART test using smartctl and i have this: SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged ; After a fats san y have obtained the same thing: SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged ; I think that it means that the disk is healty, so i was thinking if a full format of the disk(delete all partitions and then install W10, then Linux after will solve the problem. Im right in that?

Comment: @user535733 .After a long scan with the SMART utility, i also get the same message: SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: 
As i checked no HDD damage, i formatted the entire unit and installed W10 and the the linux and it worked perfectly.