# Nautilus won't copy files from mounted samba shares

Tags: networking, mount, nautilus, samba, fstab

> EDIT:
>   Thanks to
>   [How do I correctly mount a NTFS partition in /etc/fstab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-do-i-correctly-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab)
>   and  cmak.fr both the local NTFS drive and the network samba shares
>   seems to work properly now (recylce bin and file operations works)
>
> the fstab lines for the NTFS drive:
>
> `UUID=882679BB2679AAB8 /home/pietro/Storage ntfs-3g defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,dmask=027,fmask=137,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0`
>
> for the samba shares:
>
> `//192.168.2.3/media/home/pietro/Lan/MediaDrive   cifs   uid=1000,gid=1000,_netdev,credentials=/home/pietro/.smbcred,vers=1.0  0 0`
>
> vers=3.1.1 gives me error13 permission denied on the cifs mounts.

I have couple of ntfs drives on a debian server shared with samba.

If i mount them on my ubuntu 18.04 machine (either from terminal or at boot via fstab) nautilus won't copy from those drives more than 1 file at time. If i select more than one file and try to copy them it copies the first one than just "hangs" for the remaining files

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxbVi.png)

Works fine if i use the cp command from terminal or if i use the smb://address/sharename in Nautilus address bar, also works fine if i just browse to the drive from the "other locations".

Atm i solved by sharing the drives with nfs instead. But i'd like to have an username/password on my lan shares.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?
Thanx!

My fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=a8d1b759-0333-4bf0-92ef-d98f1825ca91 /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0

#   STORAGE
UUID=882679BB2679AAB8 /home/pietro/Storage    ntfs-3g        auto,user,rw 0 0

# LAN NFS
192.168.2.3:/mnt/red-media    /home/pietro/Lan/MediaDrive      nfs       rw,soft,intr,noatime,x-gvfs-show

#LAN SMB
//192.168.2.3/bk1   /home/pietro/Lan/Bck1   cifs    credentials=/home/pietro/.smbcred   0 0
```

while to mount it from terminal i used:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=pietro //192.168.2.3/bk2 /home/pietro/Lan/Bck2
```

Comment: I'd try to add the _netdev mount option ie:`_netdev,credentials=....`. Another idea -that is probably not related is adding uid and gid options `uid=1000,gid=1000,_netdev,credentials=....` -  There is the option `vers` for smb version too - Good luck

Comment: Cheers mate, adding "vers 1.0" seems to do the trick. Doesn't look like i can mark a comment as accepted answer, otherwise i would. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to add the `_netdev` mount option ie:`_netdev,credentials=.....`
 Another idea -that is probably not related- is adding uid and gid options `uid=1000,gid=1000,_netdev,credentials=....`There is the option vers for smb version too
`vers=1.0,credentials=....`

The Linux cifs kernel client has been included in the kernel since kernel version 2.5.42. For improved security and performance, SMB3 is the now the default dialect (SMB3.02/SMB3/SMB2.1 dialects are requested by default). CIFS protocol (and other old dialects) can be selected (by specifying "**vers=1.0**" or "**vers=2.02**" in the **mount options** for example). The newest, most secure dialect, SMB3.11 can also be requested (vers=3.1.1).

Comment: I noticed that adding those extra options now enabled the trash bin on the mounted drives aswell. On the 2nd NTFS drive (the storage drive shared with the win10 dual boot) on the same machine it still just asks me if i'm sure i want to permanently delete them. `UUID=882679BB2679AAB8 /home/pietro/Storage    ntfs-3g        auto,user,rw 0 0` is the fstab entry for the drive

Comment: Figured it out thanks to https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-do-i-correctly-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab. Thanks again!