# Doubts regarding my Auto ntfs mounting script

Tags: permissions, mount, ntfs

Every time i boot into my kubuntu i run

sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda3 /home/username/Ntfs/C/

sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda4 /home/username/Ntfs/Other/

I wanted to automate it hence i used `sudo crontab -e`
and added the line `@reboot /home/username/Ntfs/Mount.sh` to it

Then in konsole i ran `sudo chmod 777 Mount.sh` at /home/username/Ntfs/Other/ dir

Contents of Mount.sh is as follows

`sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda3 /home/username/Ntfs/C/
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda4 /home/username/Ntfs/Other/
exit 0`


Questions

- is it okay to mount ntfs drives inside my home dir......most guides suggested to mount them in /mnt/ dir
- is it necessary to put exit 0 at last of my script.
- because my script will anyway be executed with root privileges should i use sudo mount in the script also?
- why do we use the argument -t with mount

Comment: Why not use standard methods like editing the `/etc/fstab`? Search for how to automatically mount ntfs in this site.

Comment: @user68186 i found them extremely difficult i did try. btw does fstab mount the drives as read and write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it okay to mount ntfs drives inside my home dir......most guides suggested to mount them in /mnt/ dir

You can mount in anywhere you want ;) but the generic way is: /mnt/ for permanent disks and /media/ for removables.

> is it necessary to put exit 0 at last of my script.

No. But it is cleaner. You could expand your script to catch errors and do an `exit 1` when there is a problem.

> because my script will anyway be executed with root privileges should i use sudo mount in the script also?

Do use /etc/crontab; you can add a user to those cron tab lines so no need for sudo. Or user `sudo -i`  and use the crontab for root.

> why do we use the argument -t with mount

-t indicates the type used to mount. In this case "ntfs-3g"

> sudo chmod 777 Mount.sh

Never use 777 when 700 is more than enough. Others and group have no business with scripts run by root.

Please use /etc/fstab see for instance:

[How do I correctly mount a NTFS partition in /etc/fstab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-do-i-correctly-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab)

> btw does fstab mount the drives as read and write?

Yes if you tell it to do so. But do make sure the partition is clean: linux refuses to mount it writable if it is in an unsafe state.