# How to create a shared storage between Windows and Ubuntu dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, storage

So I have been following these steps (https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-create-a-shared-storage-drive-for-dual-boot-systems/) to create a shared storage between the Ubuntu system and Windows 11. Ubuntu DID recognise the partition but it CANNOT WRITE anything to it. It says it is a "read-only" system.
What I am asking is that how can I create a shared storage so that I can edit, add, delete files and share them between Windows and Ubuntu?
Thank you.

Comment: For the shared storage, what filesystem did you choose? Also, what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: How do you switch between Windows and Ubuntu? Do you do a full shutdown, count-to-ten, and boot? Or do you "Reboot into" Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you disable fast startup in Windows?

Comment: I restared into Ubuntu and its Ubuntu 20.04. Fast startup is disabled

Comment: Search for how to change permissions. https://frameboxxindore.com/linux/how-do-i-change-permissions-on-a-usb-in-linux.html

Comment: Permissions on Windows format partitions are set at mount. Usually automount will work or fstab entry if wanting same settings when rebooting. Note that Windows turns fast startup back on with updates, so double check that it is still off.

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072) may be helpful in order to mount a partition with a Microsoft file system (FAT32, exFAT, NTFS).

Answer (score 0):

Here all you need.
[How to mount a NTFS partition in /etc/fstab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-to-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab)
You probably need to create separate disk space for this task, it will be more secure for you.

Comment: Hello. If you read the question as asked it clearly states it does not need to mount anything. It is a permissions issue on an already available disk.

Comment: @David check **flags** it can be **read only - ro**  flag in the fstab
It is usually happen if partition with NTFS was not properly unmount .