# how to auto-mount ntfs via /etc/fstab

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, ntfs

I have been trying to automount via fstab an external hdd formatted as ntfs. When it tries to boot it goes into emergency mode or it wont give me permission to do anything but read files. I tried whats on #[113733](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-to-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab) and it still didn't work on ls -l

> drwxrwxr-x 2 ~user~ 4096 Sep  4 19:10 download 
> drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Oct 23 18:54 hdd 
> drwxr-xr-x 2 ~user~ ~user~ 4096 Oct 23 15:30 hdd2 
> drwxrwxr-x 8 ~user~ ~user~ 4096 Apr  8  2022 plex 
> drwx------ 3 ~user~ ~user~ 4096 Apr  8  2022 snap

and in fstab I have

> UUID=18F7-2D4F /home/~user~/hdd2 ntfs-3g defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,dmask=027,fmask=137,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0

Any help is welcome, I am on Ubuntu server 22.04 Kernel: 5.15.0-52-generic

Comment: For external devices, may also want to add the nofail option, so boot continues even when that device isn't available.
The nofail option is best combined with the x-systemd.device-timeout option. Was this drive mounted with Windows? If so, Windows probably left its fast startup/hibernation flag on, preventing the Linux NTFS driver from fully mounting. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: hey, i'm sorry for the delay, work has been crazy, i've tried the fast startup option on 843153, and it still gives me the same permission error, i'll be trying 145902 today

Comment: ok, i've tried a few other things
beside whats on both questions
right now i get this when i try to mount:

>sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sdb1 /home/~user~/hdd2

Comment: ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0xe4964e42  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 11065  usa_count: 35289: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0xe4964e42)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error

Comment: NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.

Comment: So have you  run chkdsk from Windows as it says in the error message? You can only fix NTFS from Windows. A very few fixs can be done from Linux but normally better to use Windows tools on Windows systems and Linux tools on Linux systems.