# Help mounting existing hardware raid in new Ubuntu 22.04 server install

Tags: server, mount, raid

As the title suggests.. I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 Server on an SSD on my server and dropped in an ARC-1880 card with an existing Raid6 set that contains roughly 8TB of data on a 14TB volume.

I am not sure what steps to take to properly mount this raid set and begin hosting it on my home network.

```
> sudo lsblk -e7 -o +FSTYPE
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS FSTYPE
sda      8:0    0   7.3T  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   128M  0 part
└─sda2   8:2    0   7.3T  0 part             ntfs
sdb      8:16   0  14.6T  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0   128M  0 part
└─sdb2   8:18   0  14.6T  0 part             ntfs
sdc      8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sdc1   8:33   0     1G  0 part /boot/efi   vfat
└─sdc2   8:34   0 930.5G  0 part /           ext4
sdd      8:48   0  74.5G  0 disk
├─sdd1   8:49   0   100M  0 part             vfat
├─sdd2   8:50   0   128M  0 part
└─sdd3   8:51   0  74.3G  0 part             ntfs
sde      8:64   1   3.8G  0 disk
└─sde1   8:65   1   3.8G  0 part             vfat
```

According to this list, the drive I'm looking to mount is "sdb".

```
> sudo mkdir /mnt/new_volume
> sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/new_volume
mount: /mnt/new_volume: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I've never worked with mounting drives in *nix before so a simple outline of steps would be fantastic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No steps needed in most cases ... a hardware RAID(*i.e. The controller card with the disks attached to it*) should be simply transferable from one server to another and will present itself to the new server's BIOS as a single/multiple logical volumes  exactly as it presented itself on the old server ... One thing to do though is to check the new server's BIOS setup and make sure volumes are correctly identified ... **Make sure you don't change anything in the settings of the RAID controller's card firmware itself though**.

Comment: Volumes appear to be correctly identified, however I cannot access the files within the volumes on the Ubuntu instance. How do I go about accessing the files and then serving them to other network clients?  ... There is nothing in the /mnt dir.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the output of `sudo lsblk -e7 -o +FSTYPE` and the output of `mount`

Comment: Added requested details to original post. Not sure what to make of the error I'm seeing.

Comment: Mount the partition `sdb2` like so `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb2 /mnt/new_volume`

Comment: Oh that seems easy. So you're not mounting the disk but the specific partition. Will these steps persist the mounted drives after a reboot?

Comment: No, you'd need to add entries to `/etc/fstab` see e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-to-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab