# can't take the ownership of my secondary hard drive

Tags: mount, 22.10, chown

i have a ntfs hard mounted on /mnt/HDD and i want to change the ownership of the files inside from root to amiroof. i tried

```
sudo chwon -R amiroof:amiroof /mnt/HDD
```

but that didnt worked and the result of ls -halg /mnt/HDD is still the same.

i have windows installed on that drive (with fast startup disabled) and that might be the cause.

Comment: "ntfs" and "chmod".  ntfs=windows. chmod=posix=linux You set permissions when mounting. Add writable to the mountpoint.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-to-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab  https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions

Comment: Read `man mount` and do something like `sudo mount -o remount,rw,uid=$(id  u),gid=$(id -g) /dev/whatever /mnt/HDD`. That will redo the `mount`, read/write, and "owned" by you.