# How to access Windows files from Ubuntu 23.10 which is installed alongside Windows Boot Manager

Tags: dual-boot, mount, 23.10

I used the Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager option, and now whenever I try accessing my SSD I run into this error:

> Error mounting /dev/nvme0n1p3 at ...SSD: wrong fs type , bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvmeOn1p3, missing codepage or helper program, or other

How do I fix this and access my Windows files on the SSD from Ubuntu 23.10?

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/q/145902/1004020 or https://askubuntu.com/q/113733/1004020

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: Open a terminal window enter...   lsblk -fa   ...then copy paste that info with quote blocks into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Booting Ubuntu alongside a Windows partition  most likely causes a bad superblock error message  because Windows 10/11 enables a form of hibernation by default known as fast startup. With fast startup the Windows filesystems remain mounted even when Windows is not running and you try to mount them again in Ubuntu.

There are two ways to disable fast startup in Windows: in the Control Panel and from an elevated command prompt.

Control Panel:

- Go to *Control Panel* -> *Hardware and Sound* -> *Power Options*.
- Select *Choose what the power buttons do*.
- Select *Change settings that are currently unavailable*.
- Under the *Shutdown settings* heading, uncheck the *Turn on fast startup (recommended)* checkbox.

Command line:

Run this command from an elevated command prompt.

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /V HiberbootEnabled /T REG_dWORD /D 0 /F
```