I can't mount Windows ntfs partition on Ubuntu (ext4)
Error when trying to mount:

What did I try to do to fix the error?

Turned off Fast Boot in the Windows Control Panel and BIOS.
Tried to manually mount the Windows partition.
Installed all available updates.

model: ASUS Vivobook 15 - X540MB (Intel Pentium Silver N5000)
Ubuntu version: 24.04 LTS
Please ask for more information if you need it.
test@test-VivoBook-15-ASUS-Laptop-X540MB-X540MB:~
ab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to n ame devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5),
# <file system> cmount point>
<type> <options>
<dump>
<pass>
# / was on /dev/sda4 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/e156ea55-a84c-4acb-af5d-e51162eaaa8c | ext4 d
efaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdal during curtin installation/dev/disk/by-uuid/AC6B-3543 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1/swap.img
none
swap
test@test-VivoBook-15-ASUS-Laptop-X540MB-X540MB:-$ |]


AT YOU OWN RISK you could run the following 'sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY' but you will first need to identify the correct NTFS partition using 'fdisk -l' & subsiture X Y. 'ntfsfix' is a utility that fixes some common NTFS problems. ntfsfix is NOT a Linux version of chkdsk. It only repairs some fundamental NTFS inconsistencies, resets the NTFS journal file and schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows. –

Could you append to your question the relevant line in your /etc/fstab file.

«Could you append to your question the relevant line in your /etc/fstab file» sorry, how?

Run a terminal. 'cat /etc/fstab' Each line refers to a mount point. Identify the one for the ntfs partition and COPY it. At the bottom of your question assert EDIT and then PASTE from the cut buffer into your question. You could then format this with the {} to make it readable. Lastly add a CHANGE note at the end of what you have updated.  Note: if there is not mount description then you probably need to add one. However, you should be able to auto mount through FILES (nautilus). This is auto mounting.  Select 'Other Locations' and mount from there.

For adding an NTFS entry into your fstab see https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-to-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab You will have to have elevated privileges for this so pre-pend 'sudo'. (Assuming you have elevated privileges

there are a lot of answers, which one should I use
