# Restricting MTP devices from being mounted by a user/group

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount, permissions, mtp

I am working on converting an Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) installation into a kiosk-like system with disabled USB storage. However, this does not prevent a user from mounting an MTP device such as an android phone.

This problem is *not the same as* [preventing auto-mounting](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/76174) of MTP devices, which has been solved in other questions on AskUbuntu.

1. I want to permanently disallow MTP and other storage devices from being mounted by a particular user or group. (Maybe by disabling mtpfs/gvfs?)
2. What some other means of connecting writeable storage devices that I should take care of (like UMTS)?

--

edit: I should add that I disabed USB storage by revoking access rights for the group in question by chown'ing /media to admin:myusbaccessgroup. Obviously, the users/groups I want to prevent from using the USB are not in myusbaccessgroup.

--

Update:

A bounty was put for this answer but no successful solution was found. Please see the answers before followed by the [chat room discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29267/discussion-between-sneetsher-and-akshay-rao).

Giving up, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 instead, since it doesn't have support for MTP out of the box. However, PTP devices still get mounted.

Comment: I wanted to add a bounty too. I could not find a solution myself. I will give an additional bounty, if we get an answer.

Comment: Have you tried changing ownership of the device (like `/dev/mtp1` or whatever) to root:root?

Comment: Then they would need sudo access, and you can disable sudo access for that user/group

Comment: @Daniel, root:rooting /dev/ but to no avail. The users/groups I need to disable this for are not in the sudo group.

Comment: @Pilot6, hope this works out!

Comment: I even removed `usb-storage.ko`. But on next reboot it got mounted using `usbfs` driver.

Comment: Perhaps the script you ran to remove usb-storage.ko can be put inside rc.local or some such startup script file? 

However, did removing usb-storage.ko disable your MTP device from mounting?

Comment: Did you root:root /dev/ recursively?

Comment: If that works I'll put it as an answer

Comment: I already that and it did not work. I don't believe these devices are mounted onto /dev/. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Pilot6, I want to add more bounty now, but can't seem to do it. Do you still wanna put some bounty from your side?

Comment: We can't add any bounty until you award this one or it expires. Please ping me if the solution is found. I will add my bounty.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get it to work using user/group permissions neither I know how libmtp mount phones volumes.

This is a solution to check the user group from `udev` side.

1. Switch to root

   ```
   sudo -i
   ```
2. Create a generic script to check GUI user and if it's in specified group

   ```
   nano /lib/udev/check_gui_user_group.sh
   ```

   Add these line to it:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   export GUI_$(grep -z USER /proc/$(pgrep -nx $1)/environ)
   groups $GUI_USER | grep -qFw "$2"
   ```

   Add executing permission

   ```
   chmod +x /lib/udev/check_gui_user_group.sh
   ```
3. **MTP devices:** Let override libmtp rules in `/lib/udev/rules.d/` .

   ```
   cp /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
   ```

   Then open it for editing:

   ```
   nano /etc/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
   ```

   Add this line just after `LABEL="libmtp_usb_rules"`:

   ```
   PROGRAM!="check_gui_user_group.sh gnome-session myusbaccessgroup", GOTO="libmtp_rules_end"
   ```

   For Ubuntu 14.04 Unity & Gnome, you may use `gnome-session`. For other desktops, check using `pstree -u` or `ps aux | grep -i session`

   The meaning of the rule: Whenever the user of `gnome-session` is NOT in the `myusbaccessgroup` group skip all libmtp rules.
4. **PTP devices:** Add another rules file

   ```
   nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-storage-remove.rules
   ```

   Add rule

   ```
   ACTION=="add", ENV{GPHOTO2_DRIVER}=="PTP", ENV{DRIVER}!="", PROGRAM!="check_gui_user_group.sh gnome-session myusbaccessgroup", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n %k >/sys%p/subsystem/drivers/%E{DRIVER}/unbind'"
   ```
5. **Other USB storage devices:** Add this rule to the rules file of the previous step.

   ```
   ACTION=="add", DRIVER=="usb-storage|uas|ums-*", PROGRAM!="check_gui_user_group.sh gnome-session myusbaccessgroup", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n %k >/sys%p/driver/unbind'"
   ```

   To know from where I get the list of drivers, try this:

   ```
   ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/
   ```
6. Reload the rules

   ```
   udevadm control -R
   ```
7. Replug your phone.

---

**Testing & Troubleshooting:**

1. Setup the group, if it's not already done

   ```
   addgroup myusbaccessgroup
   ```
2. Remove user from the group.

   ```
   deluser user myusbaccessgroup
   ```
3. Run udev monitor

   ```
   udevadm monitor -u
   ```
4. Replug that device
5. Check what was run

   ```
   udevadm test /sys/device/...
   ```
6. Add user to the group

   ```
   adduser user myusbaccessgroup
   ```
7. Redo starting from step 3.

**Notes:**

I used Kubuntu 15.04 (real machine) and Ubuntu 14.04 (fresh install in VirtualBox) for testing.

- I used Wiko Bloom (Android 4.4.2) to test MTP mode which works well in both systems.
- **I couldn't test PTP mode** because it wasn't auto-mounted, May be I'm missing something here.
- Other external storages: a flash disk & an external hard drive. Test passes for both systems.

**References:**

- `man udev` look for `PROGRAM` uses.
- [How to pause VLC playback when the headphones are disconnected?](https://askubuntu.com/a/642898/26246) , nice trick by [Stunts](https://askubuntu.com/users/264601/stunts) to import current environment variables.

Comment: Is that `export GUI_$(...` supposed to be `export GUI_USER=$(`? Also, instead of looping over groups, you could just grep: `groups $GUI_USER | grep -qFw "$2"`

Comment: @muru,  `USER=` is already in `grep -z` command,  yes that's simpler. thank you

Comment: I thought abut this. But there MUST be some better solution. And I notice that some phones get mounted when there is nothing in 69-libmtp.rules

Comment: @Pilot6, could you confirm if they are in MTP mode and how they get mounted without `dev/libmtp..` link? I know that old device like android 2.x get mounted as usb storage.

Comment: The brand new android 5.0 device gets mounted without a line in libmtp.rules. Also it does with usb-devices. When I removed `usb-devices.ko` it still got mounted with `usbfs`.

Comment: @Pilot6, I couldn't find `usb-devices.ko` & `usbfs,ko` in my system neither through http://packages.ubuntu.com . The only one i could find is `usb-storage.ko` , I have add another rule for other storage types. Could you please try it.

Comment: Sry, it is `usb-storage.ko`. I could not find `usbfs` either. But it is shown in `usb-devices` as a driver if any other driver is disabled. I do not use your script, just try to kill it for everyone just to start with.

Comment: @Sneetsher, I will try your solution out tomorrow (can't today) and get back to you. If it works well for the few MTP devices I have, I'll mark this as the answer. Please let me know if you have a better answer using Pilot6's comments about using usb-storage.

In the mean time, can you guys think of other ways a device can connect to ubuntu? Like PTP/UMTS etc? It doesn't even have to be a phone per say. I'm trying to disable any external input and outputs using the USB here.

Comment: it is really weird that such a simple user restriction is so hard to achieve in linux.

Comment: @Pilot6, I agree it shouldn't be hard, I thought about `polkit` but I have no experience with it.

Comment: I thought same and I have the same problem. I never dealt with it. I was hoping someone knows how to do it.

Comment: @Sneetsher, unfortunately this didn't work for me :( :( :( I was so hopeful. I was able to open all android phones I connected.

Is there anything (any logs etc) you'd want to check to troubleshoot?

Comment: @AkshayRao , updated the answer. You may post output of  `udevadm test ..` to http://paste.Ubuntu.com

Comment: @Sneetsher, here you go! http://paste.ubuntu.com/12435931/

Comment: @AkshayRao, I have added neew rule for PTP devices. Would you please try it.

Comment: @Sneetsher, still no luck. Both (MTP and PTP) connections are readable and writeable. However the troubleshooting did show a few non-zero return values from the tests. Maybe they would help.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12446584/

Comment: @AkshayRao , could you make another test output for mtp mode.

Comment: @Sneetsher, I was under the impression that this was for MTP mode as well. I'll get back to you in a few.

Comment: @Sneetsher, here you go. By the way, the one I pasted before was MTP (sorry about that). This one contains PTP first and then MTP. Samsung Galaxy S3

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12448398/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29267/discussion-between-sneetsher-and-akshay-rao).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same requirement in my end .

Best way to Block MTP,PTP for android is to disable the service in ubuntu .

Enter this location as root
/usr/lib/gvfs

"sudo nautilus" will be easy if you tend to use GUI

"sudo nautilus" and the n navigate to computer/usr/lib/gvfs

There will be list of services
Remove the execute permission by right clicking the appropriate service-->properties-->permission-->unckeck "execute" and change the read only access from "read only" to "none"

### Blocking MTP and PTP

Remove the execute permission for

gvfsd-mtp

gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor(for safer side)

gvfsd-gphoto2

gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor(for safer side)

---

### Apple I phone can mount through afp

so kindly Remove the execute permission for 
gvfsd-afp

gvfs-afc-volume-monitor(for safer side)

some android mobiles can use mass-storage mode to mount there SD card
change the folder permission in /media/user to 400

user- the created user in ubuntu.

chmod 400

or remove the mount permission for user..

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm on Ubuntu 16.04. Just note that you need to reboot to see the change.

Comment: hardcore approach which only works when having root access, but it works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for both Unity & Gnome, tested in Ubuntu 14.04.

1. Add the new group

   ```
   addgroup myusbaccessgroup
   ```
2. Change the owner group of gvfs monitors

   ```
   chown root:myusbaccessgroup /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-*-monitor
   ```
3. Remove permission to read & execute for public/others

   ```
   chmod 750 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-*-monitor
   ```
4. Put user1 in the group & leave user2 out or remove it from the group

   ```
   adduser user1 myusbaccessgroup
   deluser user2 myusbaccessgroup
   ```
5. Logout

Comment: This did not work. The phone still gets mounted with `usbfs`.

Comment: :( out of ideas, It hit the wall. BTW, @Pilot6 are using Ubuntu 14.04/Unity?

Comment: I use default 14.04 LTS with unity. But it does not matter much I guess.